# On the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log \left(\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}+1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, see in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html) the definition if you need it.

I can not solve this example, and I would like to know if it's possible deduce an explanation about the convergence of the series (or as (the related) an  infinite product with this [criteria of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product), note that $a_1\geq 1>0$ and for $n\geq 2$ one has $\mu(n)/\sqrt{n}+1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\geq -1/\sqrt{n}+1-\frac{1}{4n^2}>0$).

> **Question.** Please discuss if the following series  is convergent $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log \left(\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}+1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right).$$

**Many thanks.**

---

**Edit:** I was wrong with my computational evidence and problems, I unerstand better the problem now, if there are some user that want solve the question is very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ ? How many terms do you need here ? Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log \left(\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}+1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$ very different to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log \left(1+\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ ?

Comment: And how do I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges ?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @user1952009, I know the approximation from the Taylor series of the logarithm, but still I am confussed with this kind of problem. I know that that the series [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg/164878#164878)

Comment: I did not say the Taylor series, but the Taylor expansion (the 1st few terms plus an $O$ term). So what do you get with the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ ?

Comment: Thanks, isn't $x+O(x^2)$? @user1952009 I did calculations and I belive that my series is convergent.

Comment: Please solve this question, then I know where is the mistake in my reasoning, because I don't know what is it? Maybe is obvious, but now I don't understand what happen.. Many thnaks @user1952009

Comment: It is not enough, you need one more term. And what do you get **exactly** when applying it to $\sum_n \log(1+\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}})$ ?

Comment: Since $\log(1+x)\sim x$ for $x\to 0$, if $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is divergent (and it is, albeit very slowly), your series is divergent too, there is no need to consider extra terms.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I accept your words but with my calculation with an online calculator seems that is convergent. Can you do the same calculations and explain me why with this evidence one can say that is divergent the series?

Comment: @user243301: what kind of evidence do you have? You series diverges like $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \approx (\log\log\log N)^{5/4}$$ so you would need hyper-huge numbers $N$ to actually notice divergence.

Comment: No, now i belive that I was wrong, the series that seems that is convergent with Wolfram Alpha is *sum log(1+mu(n)/n-1/(4n^2)), from n=1 to 1000*, the genuine mine then seems divergent. Many thanks @JackD'Aurizio and user1952009

Comment: @ user243301 make some efforts, I have to write everything. $\log(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$ so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+ \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{|\mu(n)|}{2 n^2}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$. So it reduces to showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{|\mu(n)|}{2 n^2}$ diverges i.e. that the series for $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{\zeta(2s)}{2\zeta(s)}$ cannot be convergent at $s=1/2$, which needs proving the theorem that if $F(s)$ converges at $s = s_0$ then it has no poles on $Re(s) = Re(s_0)$ @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: You  and all users provide nice answers are generous , but I was confussing, and I know that some of my questions I didn't the best efforts. Thanks, now I read your calculations @user1952009

Comment: I meant the series for $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}- \frac{\zeta(s)}{2\zeta(2s)}$. And for your original series it works exactly the same.

Comment: I [added a proof of the needed theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) @JackD'Aurizio